# How to add polynoms in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I have the following task:

> Write a method that will add two polynoms. I.e 0+2*x^3 and 0+1*x^3+2*x^4 will give 0+3*x^3+2*x^4.

I also wrote the following code:

```
add_poly(+A1*x^B1+P1,+A2*x^B2+P2,+A3*x^B3+P3):-
    (
       B1=B2,
       B3 = B2,
       A3 is A1+A2,
       add_poly(P1,P2,P3)
    ;
       B1<B2,
       B3=B1,
       A3=A1,
       add_poly(P1,+A2*x^B2+P2,P3)
    ;
       B1>B2,
       B3=B2,
       A3=A2,
       add_poly(+A1*x^B1+P1,P2,P3)
    ).
add_poly(X+P1,Y+P2,Z+P3):-
    Z is X+Y,
    add_poly(P1,P2,P3).
```

My problem is that I don't know how to stop. I would like to stop when one the arguments is null and than to append the second argument to the third one. But how can I check that they are null?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several remarks:

Try to avoid disjunctions `(;)/2` in the beginning. They need special indentation to be readable. And they make reading a single rule more complex — think of all the extra `(=)/2` goals you have to write and keep track of.

---

Then, I am not sure what you can assume about your polynomials. Can you assume they are written in canonical form?

---

And for your program: Consider the head of your first rule:

```
add_poly(+A1*x^B1+P1,+A2*x^B2+P2,+A3*x^B3+P3):-
```

I will generalize away some of the arguments:

```
add_poly(+A1*x^B1+P1,_,_):-
```

and some of the subterms:

```
 add_poly(+_+_,_,_):-
```

This corresponds to:

```
add_poly(+(+(_),_),_,_) :-
```

Not sure you like this.

So this rule applies only to terms starting with a prefix `+` followed by an infix `+`. At least your sample data did not contain a prefix `+`.

Also, please remark that the `+`-operator is *left associative*. That means that `1+2+3+4` associates to the left:

```
?- write_canonical(1+2+3+4).
+(+(+(1,2),3),4)
```

So if you have a term `0+3*x^3+2*x^4` the first thing you "see" is `_+2*x^4`. The terms on the left are nested deeper.

---

For your actual question (how to stop) - you will have to test explicitly that the leftmost subterm is an integer, use `integer/1` - or maybe a term (*)/2 (that depends on your assumptions).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that polynomials you are speaking of are in 1 variable and with integer exponents.

Here a procedure working on normal polynomial form: a polynomial can be represented as a list (a sum) of factors, where the (integer) exponent is implicitly represented by the position.

```
:- [library(clpfd)].

add_poly(P1, P2, Sum) :-
    normalize(P1, N1),
    normalize(P2, N2),
    append(N1, N2, Nt),
    aggregate_all(max(L), (member(M, Nt), length(M, L)), LMax),
    maplist(rpad(LMax), Nt, Nn),
    clpfd:transpose(Nn, Tn),
    maplist(sumlist, Tn, NSum),
    denormalize(NSum, Sum).

rpad(LMax, List, ListN) :-
    length(List, L),
    D is LMax - L,
    zeros(D, Z),
    append(List, Z, ListN).

% the hardest part is of course normalization: here a draft

normalize(Ts + T, [N|Ns]) :-
    normalize_fact(T, N),
    normalize(Ts, Ns).
normalize(T, [N]) :-
    normalize_fact(T, N).

% build a list with 0s left before position E
normalize_fact(T, Normal) :-
    fact_exp(T, F, E),
    zeros(E, Zeros),
    nth0(E, Normal, F, Zeros).

zeros(E, Zeros) :-
    length(Zeros, E),
    maplist(copy_term(0), Zeros).

fact_exp(F * x ^ E, F, E).
fact_exp(x ^ E, 1, E).
fact_exp(F * x, F, 1).
fact_exp(F, F, 0).

% TBD...
denormalize(NSum, NSum).
```

test:

```
?- add_poly(0+2*x^3, 0+1*x^3+2*x^4, P).
P = [0, 0, 0, 3, 2]
```

the answer is still in normal form, denormalize/2 should be written...

Comment: Nit: better use `use_module(library(clpfd))` or even better `use_module(library(clpfd),[])`.

Comment: ... or maybe even better and more intention revealing: use_module(library(clpfd),[transpose/2]).

Comment: @false: but I get an error using the proposed syntax:import/1: No permission to import clpfd:transpose/2 into user (already imported from ugraphs), thus I'm forced to declare a module...

Comment: The general problem behind is that you have imported ugraphs completely. No? So you should indicate precisely what you want (I know this **is** tedious ...). But in the particular case it is probably the best to do what SICStus did: rename to `transpose_ugraph/2`. If SICStus can change, this should not be too difficult for other systems. Ideally such things would be addressed by the [Prolog prologue](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue).

Comment: @false:now I'm struggling to understand **why** ugraph gets (auto?)loaded...I don't have it in .plrc